# check for Azure AD roles contitionally

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, user-roles

I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource to check wheather a user has a specific role.
Therefore I'm checking like this:

```
HttpContext.ValidateAppRole(writeRole);
```

Unfortunatelly I have multiple roles and it's enough when the user has anyof the given roles, but ValidateAppRole() throws an exception if the roles don't match. Is there an option to check if the user has any of the roles?

Comment: I think you can use [ms graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list the Azure AD roles a user has.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yes it has been solved. Thanks. But it was my bad. See my answer..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use MS graph api.  You can call [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api to get the information of the Azure AD user role.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/memberOf
```

You can try to use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. ValidateAppRole() does check if only one AppRole fits.

So the user doesn't have to have all of the roles. It's enough when the user only has one of them..